# Пунктуация

Tags: запятая

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли в этом предложении запятые? "На детские утренники я надевала наряд лисы из старого мультика и читала стишки".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми. Запятая перед И не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: На утренники... *учила* стишки, не читала. Да и *учила* с *надевала* как-то не очень в однородности... 
Надевать платье, костюм... не наряд.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы правы. Но меня в данном случае интересует именно пунктуация, не наполнение. Подскажите, а в таких примерах запятые верно расставлены?
1)На детские утренники я надевала такое же платье, как у Снегурочки из мультика и пела песню.
2)На детские утренники я надевала платье лисы, изображенной на книжных страницах, и пела песню.

Comment: Сравнительный оборот надо обособлять: На детские утренники я надевала такое же платье, как у Снегурочки из мультика, и пела песню.

Comment: Кстати, об однородности сказуемых. Грамматически однородные члены являются семантически однородными, если они раскрывают какую-то общую тему. В данном случае в качестве общей темы выступает временная последовательность действий.

Comment: София, спасибо, что помогаете!

Comment: >В данном случае в качестве общей темы выступает временная последовательность действий.

Временная последовательность должна задаваться иначе. Напр., так: *"На детские утренники я приходила в платье Снегурочки и пела там её песни"*. В исходном же предложении представлен смысловой гибрид: подготовка (костюмирование) и исполнение (уже по ходу) артномера (декламация, пение). Если же положить в основу только подготовку, что и есть в исходном предложении доминантой, то однородность темы может выглядеть так: *"На детские утренники я надевала костюм лисы из старого мультика и разучивала стихи"*.

Comment: Думаю, вы очень много хотите от грамматики - количество  грамматических форм значительно меньше тех смысловых значений, которые мы хотели бы выразить. Например, вопрос: Что ты делала сегодня? Играла, читала, гуляла- эти однородные сказуемые, выраженные разными по значению глаголами, раскрывают общую тему занятий  именно в данном предложении. А в других случаях они однородными могут не быть. В приведенном примере ясно следует ответ на  вопрос "Что ты делала на детских утренниках?"

Comment: Отлично! Но совсем ясным *взрослый* ответ д. б. иным, например: "Я **пребывала** там в костюме лисы и пела". Но не **надевала**!